# How to arcpy.Describe() a layer when script is run from outside of ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, ioerror

The following code will work if I run it from the ArcMap Python dialog, or from a GP tool, but **not from PyScripter IDE**:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"c:\temp\<my_mxd_name>.mxd")
layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

for lyr in layerList:
  print "Layer = " + lyr.name

  #Get all fields in the layer
  fList = arcpy.Describe(lyr).fields
  for f in fList:
    print "Field = "  + f.baseName
```

When I run the exact same code from PyScripter, it fails on `arcpy.Describe(lyr).fields` with the error `IOError: "<TOC_layer_name>" does not exist`, even though it does exist in the referenced MXD table of contents.  When PyScripter fails it opens up the ESRI file `_base.py` to the `describe` function.  I am assuming there must be something different about describing a layer in ArcMap vs calling it directly from Python, but cannot figure out what it could be.

How do I properly use the arcpy.Describe() function on a layer when I am **not running the script directly from ArcMap**?

I have figured out that if I use `arcpy.Describe(lyr.dataSource)` it functions properly, but only returns the fields from the source data layer.  However, **since I'm trying to read fields from a joined table** (which does work in the original code above when running from AcrMap), I really need to see the fields from all joined tables, not just the data source.

Comment: Have you tried incorporating the [**Add Join**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000) tool in your code?  However, it would be nicer if the MapDocument and Layer objects were join-aware.

Comment: @PolyGeo, the layers are already joined via the UI, and this is a process automation task where I am just checking for existence of joined fields, not adding the join.

Comment: Might have to be an ArcGIS Idea (for ArcGIS Professional) I think - if you go that way post a link and I will vote for it.

Comment: I just made a little test and ran the exact code that you put up there (without lyr.dataSource) and it worked for me. I ran it inside PyScripter and it printed my two layers that I joined and for one of them it printed all its fields plus the fields from the join. I did create the join inside ArcMap and then saved and closed the MXD. Are you creating the join inside ArcMap or through Python code outside?

Comment: @I-B, I followed all the same steps as you, with no luck. Created the join in ArcMap, using right-click on layer-> Joins & Relates-> Join GUI with the "Keep all records" option, and saving/closing ArcMap. **What version and service pack of ArcGIS are you running?**

Comment: I'm running 10.1 with SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, I am going to have to chalk this one up to a **bug that was introduced in Arc 10.0 SP1 or SP2**.

From what I can tell, this bug was resolved in 10.1 (as @I-B suggested, and I confirmed).  Why?  Because I uninstalled SP2, SP3, SP4, & SP5 (I never installed SP1) all the way back to Arc 10.0 (no service packs), where the same exact code was finally able to run again.

To resolve this, I added the following code:

```
try:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
except:
    #This is a workaround for Arc10.0 bug
    #This points back to the path/filename of the layer
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr.dataSource)
```