# Not able to update the "ACTION" field

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7, definition-query

Currently I am working on a GIS project where I have to update a field in a layer with some values to get my work done. Because the manual efforts are time consuming hence I added a custom addin to my project, but the addin is not updating the fields. Below is my code on the button class.

```
class C(object):
"""Implementation for Update_addin.btn5 (Button)"""
def __init__(self):
    C.enabled = False
    self.checked = False
def onClick(self):
    sel = ""
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    for layer in layers:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
        if desc.fidSet:
            sel = layer.name
            break

    if sel != "":
        if arcpy.Describe (sel).FIDSet:
            if selection == "Water Projects":         #for water projects.
                with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (sel, "ACTION") as curs:
                    for row in curs:
                        row = ("C",)
                        curs.updateRow (row)

            else:          #for other projects.
                with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (sel, "Remark") as curs:
                    for row in curs:
                        row = ("C",)
                        curs.updateRow (row)
        else:
            print("No selection")
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    else:
        print("No selection")
```

After updating the "ACTION" field the selected feature should moves to another layer based on the query statement.
I am getting below error in the console window.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ks38460\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.3\AssemblyCache\{4EE0D60C-BD1E-4348-8B27-CAF3B9D13FF6}\Update_addin.py", line 41, in onClick
desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1246, in Describe
return gp.describe(value)
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 374, in describe
self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
RuntimeError: Object: Describe input value is not valid type
```

Could someone help me understand and rectify the problem in the above code.

I am using ArcMap 10.3 and Python 2.7.

Comment: mmm, your code looks fine to me. Maybe you can try with `desc = arcpy.Describe(layer.dataSource)` as suggested in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/67049/9518.

Comment: @umbe1987 It says `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ks38460\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.3\AssemblyCache\{4EE0D60C-BD1E-4348-8B27-CAF3B9D13FF6}\Update_addin.py", line 221, in onClick
    if desc.fidSet:
AttributeError: DescribeData: Method fidSet does not exist`.

Comment: Ok, the first problem then seems solved as you get the error on the next line. Anyway, it should be `FIDSet` not `fidSet`. Python is case sensitive. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/layer-properties.htm

Comment: @umbe1987 ohh....it still says `method FIDSet does not exist.`

Comment: Always in the same line (`if desc.FIDSet:`)?

Comment: @umbe1987 yes...line 221 which it is.

Comment: Do you have group layers in your mxd? Check if it so doing something like `if layer.isGroupLayer: print("I AM A GROUP!"). If it is, maybe (MAYBE) it will not have the FIDSet method. Just a guess though.

Comment: @umbe1987 No, it's not a group layer.

Comment: There is a definition query in the water_edit layer which is added 4 times in the TOC. Each layer has a query so that it will show only U, C, or LM populated features in respective layers whenever a user make a change to water_edit layer.

Answer (score 3):

Add a try/except block around the call to the desc.FIDSet property. It's likely that there are several layer types that do not support that method (group layer, raster layer, etc.). I'm not sure where the stdout is logged to for addins, but you seem to be getting a traceback so this should at least help you identify what layer is failing to report FIDSet.

```
class C(object):
    """Implementation for Update_addin.btn5 (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        C.enabled = False
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        sel = ""
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
        for layer in layers:

            try:
                desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
                if desc.FIDSet:
                    sel = layer.name
                    break
            except AttributeError as e:
                print("FIDSet failed on layer - {}".format(layer.name))

        if sel != "":
            if arcpy.Describe(sel).FIDSet:
                if selection == "Water Projects":         #for water projects.
                    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(sel, "ACTION") as curs:
                        for row in curs:
                            row = ("C",)
                            curs.updateRow(row)

                else:          #for other projects.
                    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (sel, "Remark") as curs:
                        for row in curs:
                            row = ("C",)
                            curs.updateRow (row)
            else:
                print("No selection")
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        else:
            print("No selection")
```

Edit - Now, if you've identified the layer type that is causing the error you can account for it in an additional if statement - something like:

```
...
desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
if desc.dataType == 'FeatureLayer':
    if desc.FIDSet: 
        sel = layer.name
        ...
```

Comment: It says 'selection' is not defined. and 'FIDSet failed on layer - merged_landmarks'. I think the error is in the selection variable which I should write by referring to its class.

Comment: Its working now but still says that FIDSet failed on layer - merged_landmarks.

Comment: What type of layer is `merged_landmarks`?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. If you now know what layer type is causing the error, add an additional if statement to avoid calling .FIDSet on that layer type.

Comment: @smiller `merged_landmarks` its a group layer.

Comment: Agreed, see Ben's edit. The group layer doesn't have the FIDSet to report.

Comment: @KeshavSharma if this answer solved your problem can you mark it as accepted?